# Notification after certain amount of steps taken. Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Using Swift is it possible to call up a notification after a certain amount of steps taken? If so, any tips on where to start? I'm looking to do this when the app is closed or in stand-by. I just want to make sure this is possible before I start to try to make it work.

Sorry, some more clarification...  What I have currently is an app with a scheduled local notification. What I'd like to do instead is have this notification pop up when the user has take a certain number of steps. So for example after 100 steps pop up a local notification and I want this done when the app is closed or in stand-by. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question... could you explain more please? Because I know you can't call up a Notification into the app, or you can do this with Web Service... So please, explain a little more.

Comment: Edited with a bit more info.

Comment: I believe that this will be possible on iOS 10

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use Push Notification, you can't send it from into the app. APN make a communication with your server to send Push Notification to your app. So, I you want make Notifications maybe you could to call up some web service from your app and this send a Push Notification to your app.